# want to set codeigniter join query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

hi i ma try to join with two table.
this i my simple sql query

```
$sql="SELECT windows_users_image_upload.*, `windows_users_info`.`display`
                FROM `windows_users_image_upload`,`windows_users_info`
                WHERE `windows_users_info`.`user_id` = `windows_users_image_upload`.`user_id`
                AND ".$field."=".$value;
```

its work fine but i want to set this to codeingter way
and try something like this.

```
$this->db->select("windows_users_image_upload.*,windows_users_info.display");
        $this->db->from("windows_users_info,windows_users_image_upload");
        $this->db->where("windows_users_image_upload.".$field,$value);
        $this->db->limit($takeTuple, $startTuple);
        $this->db->join("windows_users_image_upload,windows_users_image_upload.user_id = windows_users_info.user_id");
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();
```

but its show me error
**Message: Missing argument 2 for CI_DB_active_record::join()**

how can i fix this.
thanks.

Comment: try `$this->db->join("windows_users_image_upload","windows_users_image_upload.user_id = windows_users_info.user_id");`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use a join in CodeIgniter:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces:
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id1
```

You can see it in the User-Guide of CodeIgniter.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove de second table in from command:

Example:

```
 $this->db->select('windows_users_image_upload.*,windows_users_info.display');
 $this->db->from('windows_users_info');
 $this->db->join("windows_users_image_upload","windows_users_image_upload.user_id = windows_users_info.user_id");
 $this->db->where("windows_users_image_upload.".$field,$value);

 $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: $this->db->select("windows_users_image_upload.*,windows_users_info.display");
     $this->db->from("windows_users_info");
  $this->db->where("windows_users_image_upload.".$field,$value);
     $this->db->limit($takeTuple, $startTuple);
     $this->db->join("windows_users_image_upload","windows_users_image_upload.user_id = windows_users_info.user_id");
     $result = $this->db->get()->result();